# How to get selectable div value or id in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-selectable

I was trying to get selected div value or id using jquery selectable .My problem is i have div inside for loops so when i m trying to get value or id it is giving me only first div value or id.Below is my code.

```
<input type="text" id="mod">
    <div class="row">
      <?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){ ?> 
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 list"   >
        <div class="dashboard-stat blue cmp" value="<?php echo 'test'.$i; ?>" id="<?php echo 'test'.$i; ?>">
          <div class="visual">
           <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="details ">
            <div class="desc" > akak</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php }?>
    </div>
```

When i am selecting div it should give value of cmp div.But when i m selecting every time same value is coming.I am trying to get this value inside hidden text box.Below is my JS code.

```
$(".list").selectable({
    stop: function() {
     $(".cmp", this).each(function() {
      var index  =$(this).attr('data');
      console.log($('.cmp').attr('id'));
      items += ("," +(index));
     });
      $('#mod').val(items);
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

`$('.cmp').attr('id')`

which will give you all div with class value having `cmp` and calling `attr('id')` will give you id of first div only.

As you are iterating through list of divs, you must use `$(this)` which will give you the current div in the loop as shown below

`$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: thanku Bhushan,i was doing this silly mistake.how to append all selected value to text box?

Comment: change `items += ("," +(index));` to `items += $(this).attr('id') + "," ;` and you will get the comma separated ids

Comment: thnku bhushan.i tried this ,it is giving me only one value .if i select multiple it gives me only current div value.it is replacing text  value with current select div,i want all div values to text box.

Comment: i am using this fiddle ,but in my case i have div and i need all div values to text box. http://jsfiddle.net/Jk6ZH/42/

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking into documentation at this URL: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize

it will give you exactly what you need.

Comment: i goto url .thnku it is working but i m not getting all values to text box .i m getting only one value when i m selecting .how to append all selected values to text box.

Comment: Here is the basic idea of what you're trying to accomplish as I understood: http://jsfiddle.net/QFm7K/

Comment: thnku but i am using selectable so user can select nd unselect,but in ur fiddle it is duplicating values.

Comment: If you want to select multiple elements using JQuery Selectable you can simply hold Ctrl and click on the elements. In your code it works fine.